# Unable to add options to datatables in ruby 5 app

Tags: jquery, datatables, coffeescript, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-5

Rails 5.1.6 and Ruby 2.4.1

While my table is somewhat styled using bootstrap 4, I have been unable to add any custom options to my table (buttons, colReorder, etc).

coffeescript:

```
$ ->
  $('#results_datatable').DataTable
      buttons: [
        'copyHtml5',
        'excelHtml5',
        'csvHtml5',
        'pdfHtml5']
      destroy: true 
      JQueryUI: true
      colReorder: true
      scrollY: "400px"
      sorting: [[ 0, 'asc' ]]
```

application.js:

```
//= require jquery3
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require datatables
//= require_tree .
```

application.scss:

```
@import "jquery-ui";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "bootstrap";
@import 'datatables';
```

[screenshot of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B05jG.png)

I've used the datatables library before, but never with coffeescript, and never in a RoR app (new to ruby as well), so it's entirely possible my problem could be because of one (or more) of the above files. Or maybe I'm missing an important gem? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Transpiling your coffeescript via the [official online tool](http://coffeescript.org/#try:%24%20-%3E%0A%20%20%24('%23results_datatable').DataTable%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20buttons%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'copyHtml5'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'excelHtml5'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'csvHtml5'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'pdfHtml5'%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20destroy%3A%20true%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20JQueryUI%3A%20true%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20colReorder%3A%20true%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20scrollY%3A%20%22400px%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20sorting%3A%20%5B%5B%200%2C%20'asc'%20%5D%5D) gives the following output:

```
$(function() {
  return $('#results_datatable').DataTable({
    buttons: ['copyHtml5', 'excelHtml5', 'csvHtml5', 'pdfHtml5'],
    destroy: true,
    JQueryUI: true,
    colReorder: true,
    scrollY: "400px",
    sorting: [[0, 'asc']]
  });
});
```

Which looks correct syntactically (Though you don't need the commas in your array of buttons, they are optional in Coffeescript). My guess is something isn't imported correctly, probably the `buttons` and `colVis` plugins. (though they may be included in the `datatables` js/coffee file you are importing.

To rule that out, try using the js & css from the the [DataTables CDN](https://cdn.datatables.net/), including all the plugins:

```
<!-- Datatables & Bootstrap 4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

<!-- Buttons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>


<!-- colVis -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No changes after adding all CDN's. What is odd is the table responds to the scrollY and sorting options, but not to the others (before and after adding CDN's that is).....